# Why do I need static here?

Tags: c++, static, constants, init

Why I can write this:

```
class VoiceManager
{
public:
    static const int mMaxNumOfVoices = 16;
    Voice mVoices[mMaxNumOfVoices];

private:
};
```

but I can't use this:

```
class VoiceManager
{
public:
    const int mMaxNumOfVoices = 16;
    Voice mVoices[mMaxNumOfVoices];

private:
};
```

It says: "*a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object*"

But in both case, `mMaxNumOfVoices` is a `const` and will be init before `mVoices` init (compiler follow the declaration order, no?).

But it requires `static`. Why?

Comment: Context and the error message, please.

Comment: Perhaps because it would not know until runtime what `mMaxNumOfVoices` would be? And using `static` forces this value to be known.

Comment: I think only `const` does not make it a compile-time constant whereas `static const` does

Comment: I don't understand the down-votes. It's a good question about the subtlety of `const` semantics.

Comment: @StoryTeller I just upvoted the question. It is disheartening sometimes at the rapid down voting. I understand why it is there, but sometimes it can be frustrating.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Array bounds must be known at compile-time. Though your initialisation is written there in the code, it can be overridden at runtime by a constructor. Hence your non-`static` member variable is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: "it can be overridden at runtime by a constructor" uhm, no! It's a const. It can't be overridden (or at least, it shouldn't).

Comment: @paizza - [Yes it can](http://ideone.com/kcdFBe). A non-static member variable can always have its value set in a constructor, even if it's provided with a default initializer.

Comment: @paizza: The initializer can be overridden, as StoryTeller demonstrates.

Comment: Didn't know that I can re-init a const if "init" as CTOR/member initializer lists. This explain why! Nice to know. Thanks.

Comment: @paizza For non-static members, the in-class initializer is only used if there was no ctor initializer for that member.  In which case it's equivalent to providing the same value as a ctor initializer.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` keyword means read-only, not constant, is like a not-be-changed promise for a specific part of the program. If you have a pointer-to-const then other parts of the program may change the value while you're not looking.

But a `static const` is guaranteed that remains unchanged for the rest of the program. The storage for the object is allocated when the program begins and deallocated when the program ends. Only one instance of the object exists. All objects declared at namespace scope (including global namespace) have this storage duration.

Comment: This usage of `const` also guarantees the variable will remain unchanged for its lifetime ; the case about pointer-to-const doesn't apply to this code.   Also, static consts might have no storage at all if they are not odr-used; but any static that does have storage, could have its initialization delayed until first use, and might not be a constant expression.   This code (not in a class) demonstrates that your explanation isn't right : `static const int x = foo(); int y[x];` - error